# JSON Schema Catalog with relative URL in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, jsonschema

I have multiple JSONs schemas for verifying different YAML file types.
I have collected them all in a JSON catalog (similar to [the official schema store catalog](https://www.schemastore.org/api/json/catalog.json).

In my catalog I have those schemas with their file types together, and it looks like the following:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/schema-catalog.json",
    "schemas": [
        {
            "name": "My Schema 1",
            "fileMatch": [
                "*.schema1.yaml"
            ],
            "url": "https://url.to.my/schema1.json"
        },
           {
            "name": "My Schema 2",
            "fileMatch": [
                "*.schema2.yaml"
            ],
            "url": "https://url.to.my/schema2.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using VS Code and the [Red Hat YAML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml) Plugin. In this plugin I can

a) add multiple schemas to my project via the `yaml.schemas` setting, but I need to add the file match again. -> Basically it will ignore my efforts of the catalog and needs all the schemas to be added again. That means I have to do the work another time.

b) add a url to schema catalog via `yaml.schemaStore.url`. But it will not take my relative or absolute path, only any normal URL.
That means, that this will not work for me.

```
{
    "yaml.schemaStore.url": "C:/dev/project/some/sub/folder/to/schema/catalog.json",
}
```

This will also not work for me, and would be the preferred way.

```
{
    "yaml.schemaStore.url": "./some/sub/folder/to/schema/catalog.json",
}
```

Is there a way (or other plugins) to add a schema catalog via relative path to my project?

Comment: Relative URLs are not supported at this time for schema stores, while they are supported for schemas.